# Redirect 301 HTACCESS one rule for many URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, permanent

i've many urls (like 1000) and for the moment i'm unable to do a rewritemap, and of course i cannot put 1000 lines of 301 redirects in my .htaccess, so my situation is:

i've many urls like these:

```
www.site.com/idproduct-keyword1-keyword2-keyword3.html
```

and wish to redirect to

```
www.site.com/idproductDIFFERENT-keyword1-keyword2-keyword3.html
```

other example

old url:  `www.site.com/idproduct-keyword1-keyword2.html`

new url: `www.site.com/idproductDIFFERENT-keyword1-keyword2.html`

so the only thing that change in urls is the idproduct..other things remain the same..so i wish to know if there's a way to match with one rule... is it possibile in some way ?

Comment: What is `idproductDIFFERENT` ketword? Is it same in each rule?

Comment: idproduct is an id of the products, old urls have for example this id `24386` and in new url is like `28493`, how to mantain the correlation ? it's the only thing that changes in urls, everything remains the same...

Comment: Then it is a problem where `RewriteMap` would have been handy since you still need to maintain a mapping between old and new product id. I will try and think of something in absence of `RewriteMap` feature.

Comment: thanks @anubhava;) very last option will be putting 1000 lines in the .htaccess ... i tried in the past, with about 30.000 lines in htaccess (dedicated server) and was OK.... you feel the 'slow' but at least it works...and SEO will be respected ;) thanks thanks thanks :)

Comment: Yes that last resort is always there. Do you have PHP running on your system?

Comment: Yes ! it's a dynamic CMS (Prestashop) so with php/mysql ;)